# Is it possible to use @AutoConfigureRestDocs with restassured instead of mockmvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restdocs

Spring Boot 1.4 introduces `@AutoConfigureRestDocs` (See http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-rest-docs). The docs state:

> It will automatically configure MockMvc to use Spring REST Docs and remove the need for Spring REST Docs' JUnit rule.

I would like to use the restassured support of Spring REST Docs instead of mockmvc. Can I do this with `@AutoConfigureRestDocs` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not at the moment. `@AutoConfigureRestDocs` builds on top of Spring Boot's testing support being able to auto-configure `MockMvc`. There's no support for auto-configuring REST Assured which the REST Docs auto-configuration could then build upon. If it's something that you'd like to see in Spring Boot, please [open an enhancement request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/new).

Comment: Thanks. I have created https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7228